# Knockout js won't call in custom template admin UI component form

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have call custom template file in UI component and try to call knockout js in custom template but it won't call, I have built it like this. Please let me know if anyone has an idea.

> Feed/view/adminhtml/templates/feedimages/file.phtml

```
<h2>Emipro Knockout template call here..</h2>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Module_Shoppingfeed/js/jsfile": {
                "uploadUrl": "test",
                "feedMedia": "test1234"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

> jsfile.js

```
    define(['ko'], function(ko) {
        return function(config) {
            this.message = ko.observable(config.exampleMessage);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the console error you got?

Comment: not geeting any error and  not calling js file in Network..

Comment: Can you pls post your xml code....which is calling your js file?

Comment: calling js from PHTML file

Comment: i think you should call any js function by creating Uicomponent by xml

Comment: ok but i want to know why js not calling from phtml file.